# CSS (webkit): overriding top with bottom on absolute-positioned element

Tags: css, webkit, css-position

I'm having a problem with overriding some plugin CSS. Editing that CSS directly is not really an option, as it would make updating the plugin more risky.

The problem: an element has absolute positioning, and has top:0px in the original. I want to override it by bottom:0px.

For the sake of example

```
    .element {position:absolute; top:0;}

    /* in another file */
    .my .element {bottom:0;}
```

On firefox this works ok (bottom:0 is the applied style), but safari/chrome don't seem to be get over the top:0.

I can work around this problem, but it would be nice to come up with a clean solution.

Comment: The bottom was applied in webkit's case also, and the bottom-definition was more specific. !important just makes it "more specific" so to say. The problem was, it seems to calculate top first, that's why i needed a way to reset it.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Use `top: auto` to "reset" `top` to its [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/top).

`bottom` is a totally separate property to `top` ([an element can have both a `top` and `bottom`](http://jsfiddle.net/gcJvp/)), so perhaps you won't need `bottom` anymore.

Also, make sure your override selector is [specific enough](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), but it doesn't sound like that's the problem in this case.

Comment: top:auto was what I was looking for. I tried checking sitepoint CSS reference etc documentation, but couldn't find it. Tried top:none (on random :D). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
.my .element { position: inherit !important; top: auto; }
```